# Perl difference between 2 paths

Tags: windows, perl, filepath, relative-path

How to get the difference between 2 paths ?

we've $src variable which is defined with as base path, and we're getting the modified lists into FilesList.txt.

as

```
$src = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Perl\\Index"
$_ = "C:\Users\Desktop\Perl\Index\CC\Login.jsp";
```

Now, how we can get "CC\Login.jsp" value, i'm using below code, but we're not getting the expected output. Please help.

```
$src="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Perl\\Index";
open IN, "FilesList.txt";  
while(<IN>)
{
    chomp($_);
    $final=$_;
    $final =~ s/\$src//;
    print "\nSubvalue is ---$final \n";
}
```

Comment: Try s/^\Q$src\\//

Comment: `$final =~ s/$src//;` instead of `$final =~ s/\$src//;`Remove the slash before the `$src`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regex patterns to handle path strings. There are multiple different representations of equivalent paths and the strings may not match. A regex will also pay no attention to path separators, so it will not correct for a trailing separator on the base path and it may match partial path steps like `C:\Users\Desktop\Perl\Ind`, leaving `ex\CC\Login.jsp` which is clearly wrong

You need the `abs2rel` function from `File::Spec::Functions`

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use File::Spec::Functions 'abs2rel';

my $src = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Perl\Index';

for ( 'C:\Users\Desktop\Perl\Index\CC\Login.jsp' ) {

    say abs2rel($_, $src);
}
```

#### output

```
CC\Login.jsp
```